# addClass Doesn't work

Tags: jquery, addclass

i'm trying to use .addClass() to add different paragraphs to the same  but it doesn't work, it always adds all paragraphs to the div.

here's my html code:

```
<div class="topText" id="text1">
    <a class="p1">link1</a>
    <a class="p2">link2</a>
    <a class="p3">link3</a>
    <a class="p4">link4</a>
    <div class="popUp">
    <p class="t1" style="text-align:justify;">text 1</p>
    <p class="t2" style="text-align:justify;">text 2</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

here's my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#text1 p').click(function(event){

    $('.popUp').toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: 500, height: 200}).css('visibility','visible');

  //event.target è l'elemento su cui l'utente ha cliccato
  var $target = $(event.target);

  //inibisce il comportamento standard del link
  event.preventDefault(); 

  if ($target.hasClass('p1')) {
  $('.popUp').addClass('t1');
  } 
  else if ($target.hasClass('p2')) {
    $('.popUp').removeClass('.t1').addClass('.t2');


  } 
    else if ($target.hasClass('p3')) {

  }              
    else if ($target.hasClass('p4')) {

  } 
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: What the heck does that `toggle()` function do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your goal, but addClass() doesn't create elements. It adds an HTML class attribute to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

`addClass` is for adding CSS classes to an element.  To "add" a paragraph use a more suitable method like `.append` for example. [.append docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a novice at jQuery. However, i tried to use `.append()` instead of `.addClass()` but the result it's the same, it adds always all paragraphs togheter. What I need, it's that if I click on the first link the first paragraph appears in the div, while if I click on the second link the second paragraph appears in the same div but the first disappear. 

I'm sorry for my english